# Call javascript on page from ASP.Net User Control Event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a aspx page containing a user control (inside an UpdatePanel), the page subscribes to an event raised by a button click on the control.

Is it possible to call a javascript function on the page?

```
void control1_Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Call client-side javascript function here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) - this is specifically for usage within an updatepanel.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UP1, UP1.GetType(), "alertHi", "alert('hi');", true);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be harder than this.  Is this the best way to do this or should it be a javascript event on the control?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) method.

```
void control1_Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(GetType(), "myScript"))
   {
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "myScript", "<script>alert('hello world');</script>");
   }
}
```